# Embedded PNG with a transparent background not exporting in certain area of the map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, png

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1.

I've managed to find that an embedded **PNG image (with a transparent background)**, whether saved as a part of a map or not, **is not** exported with the map itself in a right part of a map only (area cca 6-7 cm from the right edge).
I want to export the map into a PDF format. The picture **IS** exported only without the transparent background or if it's positioned somewhere else on the map (the center, left side and corners).
I've already tried to add the picture by copying it from another program and also to group it with another map elements as with a new dataframe. Nothing worked fot me.
I don't always have the oportunity and space to move it to another side of the map and I need the picture to be with the transparent background as it is the logo of a project and there are rules of how it should look like.

Any ideas what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Transparent backgrounds are not supported in ArcGIS.  You will need to upgrade to ArGIS Pro for this feature.  See [this link](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009813) for more information.

Comment: If it is not supported, how come that the image is not exported only in some cases as explained above? I am just trying to figure it out. Thanks for the reply tho.

Comment: A PNG with a transparent background is supported if added in the data view but not in the layout.